# Download a file into my working directory

Tags: r

I would like to download a file directly into my working directory
I can do this to a temp directory:
`download.file("http://www.abc.com/abc.zip",temp)`
but what do I have to replace temp with to get it to download to the working directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument of `download.file()` is `destfile` and it must be specified. I don't have a Windows machine to test this on, but both of these work on my linux box and I can't see why at least the second won't work on Windows too:

```
download.file("http://www.abc.com/abc.zip", "./abc.zip")
download.file("http://www.abc.com/abc.zip", "abc.zip")
```

The second of those indicates that if you just give a filename, the file will be download to the current working directory and saved under the stated name.

Answer (score 11):

If your url is in a variable, you can use `basename` to get the "filename" part out of it:

```
u <- "http://www.abc.com/abc.zip"
basename(u) # "abc.zip"

# downloads to current directory:
download.file(u, basename(u))

# downloads to subdirectory "foo":
download.file(u, file.path("foo", basename(u)))
```

Comment: thanks, very useful trick with `basename`! `download.file` is so stupid that it can't go just with destination directory!